# Как переносить картинки на странице?

Tags: jquery

Надо, используя библиотеку jquery, обеспечить перенос картинки на html-странице в режиме drag’n’drop.

Comment: Уточнение: нужно просто перетаскивание элемента или поддержка полноценных событий onDragStart, onDrag и onDrop?

Comment: Если интересно - могу написать код без jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio здесь не нужен. Достаточно блокнота. :)

`<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" />` - это то, что будет перетаскиваться. Можно туда вставить картинку.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: black; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" />
</body>
</html>
```

Подробнее: [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Comment: Я думаю, что смысл задания в программировании, и в поверхностном понимании DRAG AND DROP а не в подключении библиотек...